# Sorting list of dicts by value of a key (or default-value, if key is missing)

Tags: python

Imagine that you have to sort a list of dicts, by the value of a particular key. Note that the key might be missing from some of the dicts, in which case you default to the value of that key to being 0.

sample input

- input = `[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 10, 'b': 3}, {'b': 5}]`

sample output (sorted by value of key 'a')

- `[{'b': 5}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 10, 'b': 3}]`

note that `{'b': 5}` is first in the sort-order because it has the lowest value for 'a' (0)

I would've used `input.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('a'))`, if all the dicts were guaranteed to have the key 'a'. Or I could convert the input dicts to `collections.defaultdict` and then sort.

Is there a way to do this in-place without having to creating new dicts or updating the existing dicts? Can `operator.itemgetter` handle missing keys?

Comment: `input.sort(key=lambda x: x.get('a', 0))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> items = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 10, 'b': 3}, {'b': 5}]
>>> sorted(items, key=lambda d: d.get('a', 0))
[{'b': 5}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 10, 'b': 3}]
```

Or to update the existing dictionary in-place

```
items.sort(key=lambda d: d.get('a', 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Or `if` in `sorted`:

```
>>> items = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 10, 'b': 3}, {'b': 5}]
>>> sorted(items,key=lambda x: x['a'] if 'a' in x else 0)
[{'b': 5}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 10, 'b': 3}]
>>>
```